# Why is this Binomial Distribution?

Tags: statistics

A box contains four tickets, numbered $0, 1, 1, 2$.

$X=$ the number obtained on a draw

Why is $X$~Binomial$(2,\frac{1}{2})$?
$2$ trials, with success rate of $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What makes you say that it is?

Comment: 1. Compute the distribution of $X$. 2. Check the definition of Bin$(2,\frac12)$. 3. Compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF of the mentioned distribution is (for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ between $0$ and $2$)
$$\binom{2}{x}/4$$
which is $\{1/4, 1/2, 1/4\}$ for $x=0,1,2$.

This agrees with the probabilities for labels: $1/4$ is $0$ and $2/4$ are $1$ and $1/4$ is $2$.

Comment: What's the strategy for finding that distribution of $X$ is Binomial$(2, \frac{1}{2})$? Because even though they are equivalent, it is not easy to see because $X$ doesn't logically fit the definition of Binomial$(2, \frac{1}{2})$ as evident by the comments under the question

Comment: @A_for_Abacus "as evident by the comments under the question" Sorry? You mean, X trivially fits this definition, as is obvious from the comments?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus I agree it doesn't logically fit. One could define infinitely many more general distributions which, in some special case, happen to coincide with the ticket distribution. Interpreting it as a special case of the binomial distribution seems just random to me.